# Regex should works with '-' too

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-ui, extjs, regex-negation

Normally  my email  works with tmail.somthing@trak.com,unfortunately I have a situation arise like my email should work with tmail.ab-cd@track.com too

```
regex: /^tmail\.[a-z0-9\.]+@track.com$/i
```

Comment: regex: `/^tmail\.[a-z0-9\.-]+@track.com$/i`

Comment: Use the \ character to escape a character that has special meaning inside a regular expression.

Comment: I´m not sure why u added /^tmail in front also the first email you provided is not valid (double @) and you miswrote trak it should be track I think. regex: `/^.[a-z0-9\.-]+@track.com$`. W3C uses a more valid way: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@track.com$/i`

Comment: @Doomenik  Email should start with the tmail... That's why ' /^tmail\.' appended with regex

Comment: @JintoJohn Your example is "my email hould work with 'tbl.ab-cd...' too" which does not start with tmail, so for your own example to work, you have to remove that part of the regexp, period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your first example is wrong, it has twice @ in it. Your regex expect tmail followed by a `.` character. I think you wanted it this way:

If you want only to add `-`

```
/^tmail\.[a-z0-9\.-]+@track.com$/i
```

Matches: tmail.whatever@track.com and tmail.what-ever@track.com

If you want to make according to html5 standard(input type="email").

```
/^tmail\.[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_{|}~-]+@track.com$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not append `/^tmail\.` and try `^[a-z0-9\.-]+@track.com$` regular expression instead.

Comment: Email should start with the tmail... That's why ' /^tmail\.' appended with regex